# iOS xCode - POST request, JSON return, TableCells

Tags: ios, json, connection, tableview

I'm in the following situation: I have an array of beacons. I have a `php` script which returns `JSON` object based on the major and minor value of a beacon that gets send to that script.

My code works perfectly when I only have 1 beacon, because there is only 1 request. The problem now is that the following should actually happen:

```
Request > Return JSON > Parse > Save in Array > Request (final)...Read out values in Tablecell.
```

Can anyone help me here on how to assure that the next request only gets send after the previous is correctly handled and added to my ObjectArray?

Because now always get (`null`) result back for my 2nd request. (No errors in JSON or so because hordcoded it does work).

Here is some of my code:

Connection making:

```
for (int i = 0; i < self.beacons.count; i++) {
    if (self.beacons.count == 0) {
        NSLog(@"No beacons");
    }
    else {
        CLBeacon *beacon = (CLBeacon *)[self.beacons objectAtIndex:i];

        NSLog(@"Make beacon");
        self.majorValue = beacon.major;
        self.minorValue = beacon.minor;
        NSLog(@"beacon: MAJOR: %@. MINOR: %@", self.majorValue, self.minorValue);

        NSLog(@"Make Request");
        NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"minor=%@&major=%@", self.minorValue, self.majorValue]; //POST naar php die returnd adhv deze waarden
        NSLog(@"REQUEST MWITHMAJOR: %@, EN MINOR %@: ", self.majorValue,  self.minorValue);

        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];
        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://uploads.genicus.be/ruben/API/ArtworkData.php"]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];

        NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    }
}
```

Connetion finished loading (here I also have the didReceiveData etc, no problems here):

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
NSError *err;
//NSLog(@"error (%@",err);
self.artworkArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.data options:0 error:&err];
NSLog(@"Log ArtworkArray in ConnectionDidFinishLoading%@", self.artworkArray);
//NSLog(@"COUNTING: %lu", (unsigned long)self.artworkArray.count);

Artwork *artwork = [[Artwork alloc]init];
artwork.title = [self.artworkArray valueForKey:@"name"];
artwork.artist = [[self.artworkArray objectForKey:@"artist"] valueForKey:@"name"];
artwork.CreationYear = [self.artworkArray valueForKey:@"creationYear"];
artwork.categorie = [[self.artworkArray objectForKey:@"exposition"] valueForKey:@"name"];
artwork.image = [[[self.artworkArray objectForKey:@"images"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"path"];

NSLog(@"artwork Title: %@", artwork.title);

NSLog(@"artworkObject: %@", artwork);
[self.savingBeaconSpecs addObject:artwork];
NSLog(@"SavingBeaconsSpecs count: %lu", (unsigned long)self.savingBeaconSpecs.count);


[self.tableView reloadData];
```

}

Making my table:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
myTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"]; //we willen de costumcell gebruiken en niet de standaard UItableCell

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[myTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}

Artwork *artwork = (Artwork *)[self.savingBeaconSpecs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"indexPath.row %ld", (long)indexPath.row);

NSLog(@"LOG ARTWORK IN TABLECELL%@", artwork);

cell.ArtworkTitle.text = artwork.title;
cell.ArtworkCreator.text = artwork.artist;
cell.ArtworkCategory.text = artwork.categorie;
cell.ArtworkYear.text = artwork.CreationYear;

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", artwork.image]];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
cell.ArtworkImage.image = image;

return cell;
```

}

So the exact problem: All my requests after the 1st one result in (`null`) when logging the `ArtWorkArray` in `ConnectionDidFinishLoading`. The 2nd object is made but is actually empty...

Screenshot of the logs: [Link to screenshot](http://afbeeldinguploaden.nl/image/v8GJgUlP)

Comment: Were does the `self.data` you use `[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.data options:0 error:&err]`come from?

Comment: - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
 //NSLog(@"Did receive response!");
 ///NSLog(@"What is the response: %@", response);
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)theData {
 //NSLog(@"Did receive Data!");
 [self.data appendData:theData];
 // NSLog(@"Received data: %@", theData);
}